# Preventing polygons from overlapping

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, pixelsense

I'm creating a WPF application for Pixelsense where I have seven polygons. I am able to move them around using touch. Currently they overlap each other like image 1 below.

[image]

I want a shape (Shape A) to not overlap another shape (Shape B), instead it should snap into place (Shape A and Shape B end up being side by side or above and below each other) when brought near as shown below.

[image]

I have searched StackOverflow for similar problems, however, I was only able to find a few links related to checking if a point or mouse click is inside a shape. Not for complete shapes overlapping or regarding how to snap them in place.

Does anyone have any ideas regarding how I could do this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum / BBS, so their shortcode won't work here. Try to learn how to use SO's markdown syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing it. I tried adding the images using SO's syntax but it said I need to have a reputation of 10 before I can post images.

Comment: I can maybe provide a code that you can detect the overlaping. Would be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you use polygon, here some solutions to detect overlapping;

```
public static bool PointCollectionsOverlap_Slow(PointCollection area1, PointCollection area2)
{
    PathGeometry pathGeometry1 = GetPathGeometry(area1);
    PathGeometry pathGeometry2 = GetPathGeometry(area2);
    bool result = pathGeometry1.FillContainsWithDetail(pathGeometry2) != IntersectionDetail.Empty;
    return result;
}

public static PathGeometry GetPathGeometry(PointCollection polygonCorners)
{
    List<PathSegment> pathSegments = new List<PathSegment> { new PolyLineSegment(polygonCorners, true) };
    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(new PathFigure(polygonCorners[0], pathSegments, true));
    return pathGeometry;
}
```

and a more faster one;

```
public static bool PointCollectionsOverlap_Fast(PointCollection area1, PointCollection area2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < area1.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < area2.Count; j++)
        {
            if (lineSegmentsIntersect(area1[i], area1[(i + 1) % area1.Count], area2[j], area2[(j + 1) % area2.Count]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (PointCollectionContainsPoint(area1, area2[0]) ||
        PointCollectionContainsPoint(area2, area1[0]))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static bool PointCollectionContainsPoint(PointCollection area, Point point)
{
    Point start = new Point(-100, -100);
    int intersections = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < area.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lineSegmentsIntersect(area[i], area[(i + 1) % area.Count], start, point))
        {
            intersections++;
        }
    }

    return (intersections % 2) == 1;
}

private static double determinant(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    return vector1.X * vector2.Y - vector1.Y * vector2.X;
}

private static bool lineSegmentsIntersect(Point _segment1_Start, Point _segment1_End, Point _segment2_Start, Point _segment2_End)
{
    double det = determinant(_segment1_End - _segment1_Start, _segment2_Start - _segment2_End);
    double t = determinant(_segment2_Start - _segment1_Start, _segment2_Start - _segment2_End) / det;
    double u = determinant(_segment1_End - _segment1_Start, _segment2_Start - _segment1_Start) / det;
    return (t >= 0) && (u >= 0) && (t <= 1) && (u <= 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm trying to work with the first bit of code you gave (as it seems somewhat easier to follow) and I was just wondering if you could provide some further help regarding understanding it. 

I have a list of objects that are the various shapes, so I'm wondering what do I pass into the method PointCollectionsOverlap_Slow() as area 1 and 2? Should I first be detecting where a collision happens and then take the are of those two objects?

Comment: So if you have list of shape, you should have also list of points for each polygon/shape. As parameter, you should pass these points lists as form of  "PointCollection collection = polygon1.Points; "

Comment: So it will detect if there exists an intersection or not

Comment: and please have look also that project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/D-Polygon-Collision-Detection

Comment: Ok I shall try that. Thank you

Comment: I just had another question while working on this, you know how with this code I am checking for a collision between two objects? If in total I have 7 objects, how can I check all of them for collision?

Comment: It is not that big problem. Just make a list of your objects and iterate all of them inside  2x foreach loop. So you can check each single object with the other one. Inside the foreach loop you can add your collision results in to another list. you are done.